# I want to merge four bytes into one digit for serial transmission

Tags: python, c++, serialization, arduino

I want to send long values using python to an arduino board which runs c++. The serial communication breaks the 4 byte numbers up and sends them byte by byte. When I try to reassemble them on the back end, I only get a valid number for 2 bytes instead of the four bytes I sent.

Here is the python code sending instructions.

```
pos1 = int(input("pos1: "))
pos2 = int(input("pos2: "))
data = struct.pack('<ll', pos1, pos2)
ser.write(data)
```

Here is the arduino code to parse the bytes that it reads.

```
if(Serial.available()>0){
  size_t numbytes = Serial.readBytes(data, 8);
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    Serial.println(data[i], HEX);
  }
  pos1 = readfourbytes(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
  pos2 = readfourbytes(data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7]);
  Serial.println(pos1);
  Serial.println(pos2);
}

long readfourbytes(byte fourthbyte, byte thirdbyte, byte thirdbyte, byte firstbyte){
  long result = (firstbyte << 24) + (secondbyte << 16) + (thirdbyte << 8) + fourthbyte;
  return result;
}
```

I guess this means the arduino is little endian? My problem is the second position value that is read is completely off. The python code seems to be the problem however I don't know why. when I send the int values of 100 for both, I get an output of

b'd\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00'

from the python code as the binary being sent in the data variable. But from the arduino, I recieve:

64

0

0

0

6D

2

0

0

100

621

So there is a disconnect between what I am sending and what I am recieving. The baudrates are the same and there is no other obvious fault that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

All the expressions `(<any>byte << <bits>)` are evaluated as `int` that seems to be 16 bits on the arduino. Cast `<any>byte` into `long`, and you're done.

```
long readfourbytes(byte fourthbyte, byte thirdbyte, byte thirdbyte, byte firstbyte){
  long result = ((long)firstbyte << 24) + ((long)secondbyte << 16) + (thirdbyte << 8) + fourthbyte;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: So in the function parameters call those long instead of bytes?

Comment: also when I change to long, I get underflow if I choose a negative number

Comment: Please, can you give an example `long` value, and the 4 bytes transmitted? You can try to identify the cause when you use only one of the terms which are summed up.

Comment: I just sent: pos1 = 40000 and pos2 = -100. In binary, python sent b'@\x9c\x00\x00\x9c\xff\xff\xff'" The arduino recieved 40000 and -83885784

Comment: I have tried to match the struct data types with the arduino code but when i use struct.pack('<ll', pos1, pos2) I send 16 bytes total instead of 8.

Comment: The bytes python sent are in little endian and match the given values; good. How do you check the received value? Can you print it in hex?

Comment: -83885784 seems to be quite strange. It's \x28\x01\x00\xfb (\x28 could be '(' as '@' is \x40).

Comment: Arduino hex values are 40 9C 0 0 28 1 FF FF for the same input as before (40000, and -100)

Comment: Alright, you're on a good way to find the solution yourself. I'm now heading home, perhaps we can continue in chat, like StackOverflow suggests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197730/discussion-between-evan-and-the-busybee).